# How to loop through this XML data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, wordpress

XML File Output

```
<result>
<listing title="Title 1" descr="description 1" url="http://google.com"/>
<listing title="Title 2" descr="description 2" url="http://google.com"/>
<listing title="Title 3" descr="description 3" url="http://google.com"/>
<listing title="Title 4" descr="description 4" url="http://google.com"/>
</result>
```

How can I loop through this data so that I get the attributes of each listing on the list

---

This my code for display single listing attributes

```
$url = 'abcd.xml';
$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($body) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);

$listing = array_map('array_values', $xml);
if(isset($listing['listing'][0])) { 
  $title = $listing['listing'][0]['title'];
  $descr = $listing['listing'][0]['descr'];
} else {
  die("listing Post Not Available");
}


print_r($title);
print_r($descr);
```

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/n1cPi) might help

Comment: I would familiarise yourself with the php docs on reading XML. https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Do not convert the SimpleXMLElement debug output into array structure. This removes information and disables features. Use `foreach` loops and `SimpleXMLElement` methods/properties.

Comment: @berend foreach throwing error if there is only 1 XML listing item is present

Comment: you could [provide](https://3v4l.org/5Sg69) for the case where there's only one XML listing item...